# NSPredicate for max(arrayOfNSDates)

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nspredicate, max

I got problem with NSPredicate.

I got some engine where the predicates are constructed from a definition coming from a web service.

I use somethning like that:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"max({1,2,3})==3"]
```

it's great, but I need max function for NSDate objects.
Here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190 is wrote that max() function can get only array containings objects representing numbers.

Is there any solution to use this function for that (override some method, create some category for NSPredicate)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solutions is realy good, but don't solve my problem.
I got something like this:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: condition];
[predicate evaluateWithObject:nil substitutionVariables: currentForm];
```

And condition can be:

```
max($widgetWhichReturnDate.result.result,$widgetWhichReturnDate.result)
```

or

```
max($widgetWhichReturnInt.result,$widgetWhichReturnInt1.result)
```

what widget is used here depends from webservice.
So I don't like to use different functions for Date and int (or in the future maybe float, double etc)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is possible, but it's weird.  We'll have to build the format string programmatically.  Alternatively, we could built it all by creating the individual `NSExpression` objects, but that'd be a lot more code (albeit likely safer, but whatever).

```
NSDate *maxDate = ...; 
NSArray *arrayOfDates = ...; // an NSArray of NSDate objects

NSMutableArray *dateFormats = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDate *date in arrayOfDates) {
  NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
  [dateFormats addObject:format];
}

NSString *dateFormatString = [dateFormats componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CAST(max({%@}) = %%@, 'NSDate')", dateFormatString];

// format now looks like CAST(max({xxxx.xxxx, nnnn.nnnn, aaaa.aaaa, ....}), 'NSDate') = %@

NSPredicate *datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format, maxDate];
```

The trick here is to use the date's absolute time interval since the reference date as the arguments to the `max()` function, and then turn the result of *that* back into a date by using `CAST()`.  More info on how to use the `CAST()` function with dates can be found [in this blog post](http://tumblr.com/xqorqjfrz).